# Network connection slow to server, only from one device

Tags: linux, iperf

I have looked around, but there doesn't seem to be anyone with the same problem.

I am getting almost no connection from my console (laptop) to one of my servers (Raspberry Pi 2 B) . All other devices connect to it fine.

Here are the specs of interest:

Laptop: Asus i7 Ubuntu Connected by wifi, which has no problem streaming netflix, so it is unlikely the cause.

Raspberry Pi connected by ethernet directly to router.

Connection from all other devices on the network to the server over iperf shows around 95Mbit/s

Connection from laptop over iperf ranges from 1 - 20 Kbit/s

Connection from the same laptop, with ethernet instead of wifi, 95Mbit/s
(Trust me, I have ruled out the wifi as the issue, I can get fast connection speeds to all other servers over the same wifi using iperf.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, changing the IP of the wifi connection does not help.

Comment: Ok, another interesting development, I have found another device on the network with the same problem. So that's two devices cannot connect to the raspberry pi over wifi with more than about 20kbit/s . 
I know this incriminates the wifi even more, but why then would both devices be able to connect to anther server over the same wifi at 95 mbit/s ? Makes no sense...

Comment: Tearing the last few grey hairs from my head... Rebooting the modem/router combo resolves the problem temporarily...

Comment: Is this a router fault? Is there **anything** else that could be at fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone has this issue (or similar), the problem in the end was the raspberry pi itself. Hardware fault for sure. I swapped the pi for a new one, exactly the same model, placed the same sd card in, with all the same cables, and everything has been working perfectly since...